# Django Postgres search with TrigramSimilarity

Tags: django, postgresql, pg-trgm

If I use 'title' in my post_search function it works perfectly.

```
Post.objects.annotate(
                similarity=TrigramSimilarity('title', query)
                                        ).filter(similarity__gt=0.1).order_by('-similarity')
```

Although if I try to search in **'body'** instead of 'title', I'm getting 0 results.

```
    Post.objects.annotate(
                similarity=TrigramSimilarity('body', query)
                                        ).filter(similarity__gt=0.1).order_by('-similarity')
```

It is supposed to work perfectly as if I look into TrigramSimilarity documentation the keyword choices are: author, author_id, **body**, comments, created, id, publish, slug, status, tagged_items, tags, **title**, updated.

Has anybody experienced anything like this?